# Codeception - click HREF with no id

Tags: xpath, codeception

We have a table of links, each has no individual id or css class.

The XPath to the 5th link down is: (grabbed from Chrome Developer Tools - save XPath)

```
//*[@id="table_1_"]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a
```

The Click command in my testCept.php file is:

$I->click('//*[@id="table_1_"]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a'); 
However fails with a

> Link or Button by name or CSS or XPath '//*[@id="table_1_"]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a' was not found on page.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that if I change the acceptance.suite.yml to use WebDriver instead of PhpBrowser then this link does work.